# Not taking right user name while starting Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

Im attempting to start Hadoop

```
./sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

but I get the following error

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
ERROR: Attempting to operate on hdfs namenode as root
ERROR: but there is no HDFS_NAMENODE_USER defined. Aborting operation.
Starting datanodes
ERROR: Attempting to operate on hdfs datanode as root
ERROR: but there is no HDFS_DATANODE_USER defined. Aborting operation.
```

I ran this from my terminal before I execute start

```
export HADOOP_USER_NAME="myname"
export HDFS_NAMENODE_USER="myname"
export HDFS_DATANODE_USER="myname"
export HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER="myname"
export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_USER="myname"
export YARN_NODEMANAGER_USER="myname"
```

I have also created data folder and assigned it to same user group. Anything else Im missing?

Comment: did you try to start hadoop with an other user tha root ?

Comment: try to connect with `su -u myname` and than start hadoop